# Split space separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many records like this

```
ID   Tag   Arr
1    A     87 34 92
2    A     34 35 38
3    A     39 88 92
4    B     24 49 39
5    B     38 88 23
6    C     39 37 99
```

I want the end result to look like this in a fast way

```
Tag Arr No
A   87  1
A   34  2
A   92  2
A   35  1
A   38  1
A   39  1
A   88  1
B   24  1
B   49  1
B   39  1
B   38  1
B   88  1
B   23  1
C   39  1
C   37  1
C   99  1
```

This is the query i built so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.tag, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+T1.Arr  AS [text()]
            FROM Tags T1
            WHERE T1.tag = T2.tag
            and filename = 1
            and tag not in ('U')
            ORDER BY T1.tag
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Ts]
FROM Tags T2
WHERE  filename = 1
and tag not in ('U')
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this using [STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 which works for *SQL Server 2016 and later*.

```
create table tblSampleValue(Id int, Tag Varchar(10), Arr Varchar(50))
insert into tblSampleValue Values
(1, 'A', '87 34 92'),
(2, 'A', '34 35 38'),
(3, 'A', '39 88 92'),
(4, 'B', '24 49 39'),
(5, 'B', '38 88 23'),
(6, 'C', '39 37 99')

Select * from tblSampleValue

select id
 , Tag
 , [value] as Arr 
from tblSampleValue 
cross apply string_split(Arr,' ')
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9c88d245696a0c8e2933318ff5fe26d) demo.

Comment: Nice One!!!  I guess it was just a matter of time until MS built this into their SQL Server system.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to use `Split` function to split `Arr` column with space.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Split 
( @Words nvarchar(MAX)
, @splitStr varchar(50) 
)
RETURNS @Result_Table TABLE
       (
         [word] nvarchar(max) NULL
       )
BEGIN 
    Declare @TempStr nvarchar(MAX)

    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@splitStr,@Words)>0)
    BEGIN
        Set @TempStr=SUBSTRING(@Words,1,CHARINDEX(@splitStr,@Words)-1)
        Insert into @Result_Table (word) Values (@TempStr)

        Set @Words = REPLACE(@Words,@TempStr+@splitStr,'')
    END/*End While*/

    IF(LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@Words)))>0 And CHARINDEX(@splitStr,RTRIM(LTRIM(@Words)))=0) 
    Begin
        Set @TempStr=@Words 

        Insert into @Result_Table (word) Values (@TempStr)

    End /*End IF*/

   RETURN 
END
```

then use `CROSS APPLY` with `Arr` column

```
SELECT Tag,
       word,
       count(*) [no]
FROM Tags CROSS APPLY udf_Split(Arr,' ') v
GROUP BY Tag,
       word
ORDER BY Tag
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30141/10)

**Note:**

if your SQL server version higher than 2016 there is an official function you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: In 2020 you probably could start with last note ;)